# What will be the SQL query to find only same pair in a table?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
S_Name   C_ID
'A'       123
'B'       456
'A'       123
'A'       123
'C'       789
'B'       456
'C'       098
'C'       456
'B'       456
```

I want only those  S_Name whose C_ID's Doesn't change.

The answer which I want would be:

```
S_Name  C_ID
'A'      123
'B'      456
```

'C' cannot be in the result because it's C_ID is different at different places.

Comment: can you let me know what version of SQL are you using? tSQL .. etc... and also what engine? SQL SERVER etc..

Answer (score 2):

Using a `group by` on `s_name` while ensuring that the `count` of distinct `c_id` values for each grouping is `1` should do the trick.

```
select s_name, max(c_id)
  from tbl
 group by s_name
having count(distinct c_id) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   S_Name,
   MAX(C_ID) as C_ID
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY
   S_Name
HAVING
   Count(DISTINCT C_ID) = 1
```